# How to keep date format when converting CSV to XLSX with SSCONVERT

Tags: excel, csv, ssconvert

I am trying to convert a simple csv file that contains a date format as **d.m.Y** to an excel file using **ssconvert** but **ssconvert** changes the date format to **d/m/Y**

The command below without option on the format is changing the date format of the xlsx file
`ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx test.csv test.xlsx`

The command below with the format option is not working as the format option is only for *.txt.
`ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx -O "format=preserve" test.csv test.xlsx`

I am expecting that when converting a csv file with a date 10.12.2011 to receive also the same date 10.12.2011

Thanks for the help on this matter.